# publish a mail with text from SNS topic with cloudformation template

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation

I am creating a cloudformation code to publish emails to multiple recipients via SNS topic which works fine but i need the mail text to be added in same code. I am getting validation error while publishing the message. below is the code

```
AWSTemplateFormatVersion: '2010-09-09'

Resources:
  MySNSTopic:
    Type: AWS::SNS::Topic
    Properties:
      TopicName: my-sns-topic

  MySNSSubscription1:
    Type: AWS::SNS::Subscription
    Properties:
      TopicArn:
        Ref: MySNSTopic
      Protocol: email
      Endpoint: email-address-1@example.com

  MySNSSubscription2:
    Type: AWS::SNS::Subscription
    Properties:
      TopicArn:
        Ref: MySNSTopic
      Protocol: email
      Endpoint: email-address-2@example.com
  MySNSPublishMessage:
   Type: AWS::SNS::Publish
   Properties:
     Message: "status check failed"
     TopicArn: !Ref MySNSTopic







check the documentation
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. We need more specific information about what's wrong. Please describe what you're doing, show your code as a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), and clearly explain what's not working about your attempt. We're more than happy to then help :)

Comment: How do you expect to publish a message from CloudFormation? From CloudFormation you generate resources and publishing message is an event... If you check CF documentation, you will see that `Publish` doesn't exist as a valid type: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/AWS_SNS.html